# Can't use WIFI connection

Tags: wireless

I've just added Ubuntu as a dual boot OS with my laptop. Anyway I'm having issues with my wifi. It says I'm connected however I can't open any websites. I've done a bit of googling and tried some things however they didn't solve my issue. Anyway I will post the results of some common commands from this sort of problem that I'm seeing in other threads.

```
keggatron@keegan-Satellite:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release; uname -a
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"
Linux keegan-Satellite 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


keggatron@keegan-Satellite:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet [1969:1090] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems AR8162 Fast Ethernet [1179:ff1e]
    Kernel driver in use: alx
    Kernel modules: alx
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:0191]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8188ee
    Kernel modules: rtl8188ee


keggatron@keegan-Satellite:~$ iwconfig
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Terra"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 14:CC:20:56:CC:A5   
          Bit Rate=150 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-30 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:19   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.



keggatron@keegan-Satellite:~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no



keggatron@keegan-Satellite:~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
drbg                   32768  1
ansi_cprng             16384  0
ctr                    16384  2
ccm                    20480  2
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
rtsx_usb_ms            20480  0
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_usb_ms
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             172032  0
uvcvideo               90112  0
kvm                   536576  1 kvm_intel
arc4                   16384  2
rtl8188ee              86016  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8188ee
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
rtlwifi                77824  2 rtl_pci,rtl8188ee
mac80211              737280  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8188ee
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
videodev              176128  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
snd_hda_codec_realtek    81920  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
snd_hda_intel          36864  3
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
cfg80211              565248  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
cryptd                 20480  0
snd                    81920  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
soundcore              16384  1 snd
joydev                 20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
serio_raw              16384  0
toshiba_acpi           40960  0
mei_me                 36864  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 toshiba_acpi
shpchp                 36864  0
toshiba_bluetooth      16384  0
lpc_ich                24576  0
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
mac_hid                16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
rtsx_usb_sdmmc         28672  0
rtsx_usb               24576  2 rtsx_usb_sdmmc,rtsx_usb_ms
i915                 1208320  3
alx                    36864  0
psmouse               126976  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        139264  1 i915
ahci                   36864  3
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
libahci                32768  1 ahci
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
mdio                   16384  1 alx
drm                   360448  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
wmi                    20480  1 toshiba_acpi
video                  40960  2 i915,toshiba_acpi
fjes                   28672  0
```

If any of you can help me out with this I'd be very appreciative as this is quite frustrating.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the extra info that Brane requested:

```
keggatron@keegan-Satellite:~$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:8c:fa:93:30:6b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 64:5a:04:0a:80:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

keggatron@keegan-Satellite:~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:8c:fa:93:30:6b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.105/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic enp1s0
       valid_lft 7112sec preferred_lft 7112sec
    inet6 fe80::51bb:9d8e:3cfb:e968/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 64:5a:04:0a:80:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.103/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic wlp2s0
       valid_lft 7062sec preferred_lft 7062sec
    inet6 fe80::2b61:811:467f:4abc/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

keggatron@keegan-Satellite:~$ ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp1s0  proto static  metric 100 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp2s0  proto static  metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp1s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.105  metric 100 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp2s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.103  metric 600



keggatron@keegan-Satellite:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

EDIT: Results from the rest of the commands:

```
keggatron@keegan-Satellite:~$ nslookup google.com
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   GOOglE.CoM
Address: 216.58.209.206

keggatron@keegan-Satellite:~$ iptables -nvL
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ip_tables': Operation not permitted
iptables v1.6.0: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
keggatron@keegan-Satellite:~$ iptables -t nat -nvL
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ip_tables': Operation not permitted
iptables v1.6.0: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

Comment: Thanks @keggatron, would you mind running the following for me, while connected only to the wifi? `ping 8.8.8.8 -s 100 -c 3`, `ping 192.168.0.1 -s 100 -c 3`, `nslookup google.com`, `iptables -nvL` and `iptables -t nat -nvL`. I know it's a lot, but it will help.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but this is all very new to me, is the >ping 8.8.8.8 -s 100< supposed to take all day? It was still running after more than an hour. I control C'd it and this is what I got from it:
>--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5098 packets transmitted, 1100 received, 78% packet loss, time 5126837ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 76.027/246.096/622.414/197.174 ms

Comment: Here are the result from the ping 192:keggatron@keegan-Satellite:~$ ping 192.168.0.1 -s 100 -c 3
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 100(128) bytes of data.


--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1999ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from diagnostics in comments under the original question, everything is ok and your wifi connection is actually working... Extremely poorly, but working. After some googling I found out that a lot of people are apparently having problems with all variants of RTL8188 wireless chipset in Ubuntu, which you have (RTL8188EE to be exact).

You can try running the following commands to remove your current RTL8188EE driver, download and install a new one (from Larry Fingers' GIT repository, where your driver was last updated 6 days ago) that appears to solve the problem for most people. Do this while connected to the internet via wired connection:

```
cd ~
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic git dkms
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8188ee
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -v rtl8188ee
```

After you're done, reboot your computer just in case. If you get any warnings or errors while running these commands and the problem is not fixed in the end, post the errors here.

**Cleanup:**
When running `apt-get`, you can take notes which packages are already installed on your system and which ones will be installed now. After everything starts working fine, you can run `sudo apt-get remove package_name other_package_name and_so_on` to remove the newly installed packages if you like. When you're all done, you can also remove the `rtlwifi_new` directory that gets created when running `git clone` by running `rm -rf ~/rtlwifi_new`.

Comment: Awesome that worked, currently posting using WiFi!! Thank you again for all of your time and help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad I could help. I remember how frustrating it was for me, when I had similar problems with a new USB WiFi dongle... :)